# How to serialize JSON format to new JSON file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I want to save this json format in c# to a json file in my computer for offline work.
I have a Json format like this

```
    {
        "Name": "room 1",
        "TimeOpen": "6:30AM — 11:30PM",
        "Phone": "(0) 66 11111",
        "Description": "Hospital Room 1",
        "Image": "1.jpg",
        "RoomNumber": "1",
        "DepartmentType": 1,
        "Direction": "First Room of Floor 1",
        "Floor": "1"
    },
    {
        "Name": "room 2",
        "TimeOpen": "10:15AM - 8:30PM",
        "Phone": "(0) 66 5738902",
        "Description": "Hospital Room 2",
        "Image": "2.jpg",
        "RoomNumber": "2",
        "DepartmentType": 2,
        "Direction": "Second Room of Floor 1",
        "Floor": "1"
    },
    {
        "Name": "room 3",
        "TimeOpen": "7:30AM — 16:30PM",
        "Phone": "(0) 66 5738902",
        "Description": "Hospital Room 3",
        "Image": "3.jpg",
        "RoomNumber": "3",
        "DepartmentType": 2,
        "Direction": "Third room of Floor 1",
        "Floor": "1"
    },
```

and in class is :

```
public class HosRoomViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string TimeOpen { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string RoomNumber { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentType { get; set; }
        public string Direction { get; set; }
        public string Floor { get; set; }
    }
```

In client project I use this to call this API

```
public ActionResult HospitalMap(Guid hosId)
    {
        string apiRequest = string.Format("api/bv/DetailHospital?hosId={0}", hosId);
        var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:9666");
        var req = new RestRequest(apiRequest, Method.GET) {RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json};
        var rs = client.Execute<HttpContentResultPaged<List<HosRoomViewModel>>>(req).Data;
        var listApp = rs.Data;
        string jsondata = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(listApp);
        string path = Server.MapPath("~App_Data/");
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + "room.json", jsondata);
        TempData["msg"] = "Json file Generated! check this in your App_Data folder";

        return View(listApp);
    }
```

but when I run my project I have this error: 
[Could not find a part of the path: 'C:...\room.json'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Isbn.jpg)
If you want more information please tell me.

Comment: please tag this question with the language that you are working in

Comment: I just tag c# to my question, please tell me what to do next.

Comment: @Khoa you want to store the returned contents in json format in your localdisk?

Comment: yes it is @AkshayBheda

Comment: @Khoa So now in which variable you are getting your json result?

Comment: @AkshayBheda I just call this json in client side but not create the function to Serialize json

Comment: @Khoa Please explain in detail. not able to get you

Comment: @Khoa Do you want to store the results of the variable listApp into the json file on your machine?

Comment: @AkshayBheda I've read how to Serialize json data to a file but not work & come here to ask how to do it.

Comment: @Khoa Please add the code, which you tried and what error you got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your List into Text file keeping the JSON Object intact in the following way

```
using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(@"D:\FILENAME.txt"))
{
     JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
     //serialize object directly into file stream
     serializer.Serialize(file, listApp );
}
```

Comment: ok I've read this article in [Serialize JSON to a file](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeWithJsonSerializerToFile.htm)
but I don't know where I can put it and in my controller how to call this function, tks for your comment

Comment: sr for your time, i'm new and i don't know what to do

Comment: @Khoa Put that in your controller itself

Comment: I have this error when I paste the code to my client side controller :
[error](https://imgur.com/a/dnR9l)

Comment: I just update my controller in my question, If you still there please check & tell me what should I do next, tks.

Comment: i did it! Thank you!

Comment: What did you do? You must not have write access to C: drive, as it requires administrative rights. You should be able to do in D Drive

Comment: I change my mind,I'm save this json file to App_Data of my project.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong path in `Server.MapPath`. Try:

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/");
```